# solve the following ode $y'=y^2-1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

supposedly an easy ode, but get worst very quickly.
has anyone have a solution?
solve $y'(x)=y^2(x)-1$
trying integrating factor but got $y=1+ce^y$, while the solution should be expressed as x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: You have $${dy\over dx} = y^2-1$$ Rewrite it as $$ {2dy\over y^2-1} = 2dx$$  and integrate both sides. For left side you can use the method of partial fractions:

$${2\over y^2-1} = {1\over y-1} - {1\over y+1}$$

so $$\ln|y-1| -\ln|y+1| = 2x+c$$
$$\implies {y-1\over y+1} = Ae^{2x}\implies y=...$$

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: yeah but it is not a clean solution, I look for less technical solution

Comment: I haven't downvoted, in fact, I now will upvote you.

Comment: There is nothing so difficult here.

Comment: not difficult but really technical as you'll get $\frac{1}{2(y-1)}-\frac{1}{2(y+1)}$

Comment: it is worth emphasizing that there are two stationary solutions, lines $y=1$ and $y=-1$ the other solutions vary a good deal as to being above 1, or between -1 and 1, or below -1. Worth drawing some

Comment: also, the final bit is inverting a Mobius transformation, easy if you know what to do

Answer (score 0):

This is not a linear ODE, thus you can not apply the idea of the integrating factor. For the separation-of-variables method see the other answer.

This is also the most simple solvable Riccati equation. Setting $y=-\frac{u'}u$ results in $$u''=u,~~ u(0)=1, ~ u'(0)=-y(0),$$ so that $u=Ce^x+De^{-x}$ etc. or
$$
y(x)=\frac{y(0)\cosh(x)-\sinh(x)}{\cosh(x)-y(0)\sinh(x)}
$$

Comment: can you give the full solution?

Comment: Just insert into the parametrization. There is not much left to do.